# finding words in mysql huge database

Tags: php, mysql

So, i've never worked with a database this huge. We are talking about 200.000.000++ words that i want to be able to search through. How should i approach this? using the normal "where" statement would take 10+++ minutes, should i split up the database or something?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you using indexes?

Comment: try sphinx for the table engine: http://sphinxsearch.com/about/sphinx/

Comment: mysql full text index

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL FULLTEXT` indexes are quite useful when searching for words. You have to define the fields which contain the relevant text/character strings as indexes. Then you can use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (text_index_field) AGAINST ('what you need to look for');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `MySql FULLTEXT` indexing.
Use `AlTER TABLE` for create a `FULLTEXT` index on your desire column.

and from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.) Full-text indexes can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

Comment: If you copy paste content, use blockquotes and include a link to the source.

Comment: Thanks Amir. For your information there is a specific markup for citations. I edited your post.