# Finding HASH string in database (mysql and php)

Tags: php, mysql

So, I've got this weird idea, of matching hashes with words. However, since the odds of getting a match, is small, i would need a large database with hashes and words. I've already got a huge database with millions of random/real words and the hash corresponding to the word.

The problem however, would be searching. I got no experience on this large scale of databases. So, i did some random testing with "WHERE" statemens in MySQL etc. Guess what, it took me more than 14 minutes finding a match, before the SQL was done searching and finding the HASH and giving me the WORD in return.

How should i be able to speed up this process? I'm using PHP and MySQL. Would a need to install something else onto my server? or is there something already built into mysql that i could use?

Comment: look into `sphinx` search

Comment: did a google search on that, did not quite understand how it works?

Answer (score -1):

Add a primary key which is auto incrementing and name it id.

I wrote a script which takes all the words in `/etc/dict` and ran md5 over them, writing out their name and hash to create something like this:

```
"2af2fc92ed1ee8080d9ab015ab053074", "Windex's
"bfa818f0cac66108daef757706e97a99", "Windhoek
"88d0e322fb73a2e971bc982bd348c777", "Windows
```

My route of doing this was very hacky so I wont post my way of achieving it, but overall it was quite simple and just essentially was based around:

```
while read line
    do
        echo $line | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
    done
```

So I created a database table:

```
CREATE TABLE whashes
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     hash varchar(32), 
     word varchar(16)
    );
```

And used:

```
INSERT INTO whashes
(hash, word)
VALUES
```

With the output of my script above. Running a test for speed.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `whashes` 
WHERE word LIKE  "poop"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Runs in 0.0324 sec. This is with 100k words and should stay around that speed

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `whashes` 
WHERE hash LIKE  "b538baf8573b52b5bcfdd551fffa6e9d"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Runs in 0.0202 sec.

From my understanding using an auto incrementing primary id integer key the computer is able keep a large amount of id's in cache and do somewhat of a binary search on those values. Without a key like this the database engine has to loop through each value checking it, compared to one check which reduces the amount needed to be checked by half each time. However, this explanation may be slightly incorrect however someone else may be able to explain further / correct me if I'm wrong. Just doing something as simple as this should give you a large improvement.

Comment: How would this speed up the process?

Comment: @DarylGill If your still curious I've tried to add a bit of background.

Comment: Did exactly as you said, and ran the sql search. 9minutes, for running all the records. This is a 9.1GB table.

Comment: @Dexty Do each of the rows have an id set? If not run through each row and increment the id by 1

Comment: @Dexty also, what database engine are you using. My advice is tailored to innoDB (unknown on myISAM)

Comment: @jett I'm using innoDB, and yes, each row has an ID set.

Comment: @Dexty Hmm. Here's how someone else solved something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460991/finding-words-in-mysql-huge-database?rq=1

Comment: @Dexty Another thing I've just thought of, it may have been due to me having my words ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Added indexes and configured the mysql config-file to match my speccs on the server. Works like a charm :-)